# Prove that absolute value of x-y is less than alpha and beta.

Tags: proof-writing, absolute-value

Prove that if  $\alpha < x < \beta $ and $\alpha < y < \beta  $ then $ \left | x-y \right |< \beta -\alpha $. Interpret the result geometrically as a statement about the interval $\left ( \alpha ,\beta  \right )$.

I know that it's true but I don't know where to start...

UPDATE:

Suppose that $$x\geq y$$
$$x <\beta$$
$$x-y<\beta-y $$

---

$$\alpha <y $$
$$\alpha +\beta -y<\beta$$
$$\beta-y<\beta-\alpha$$
$$\Rightarrow \left | x-y \right |<\beta -\alpha $$

Comment: @AdamRubinson, thanks for noticing, fixed it

Comment: Try to prove the two cases $x\ge y$ and $x<y$ separately. Please update your question with your attempts

Comment: @BenjaminWang is x = y?

Comment: @runtotherescue Is $x=y?$ Uh oh. There might be deeper issues here. Please express in your own words what you think the problem statement says.

Comment: I'm really confused. What difference does it make if x >= y?

Comment: Do you have any idea what is going on in this problem? Have you drawn a diagram/ several diagrams on (a) number line(s) to get to grips with the question? If not, you should do so. Seeing what is going on is the first (easy) step. Solving the problem with logical deduction is actually the hard part if you want to do it rigorously.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I did try to draw it. I understand that if you draw a number line from alpha to beta, the numbers x & y are in between them. I understand that their distance (absolute value) will be surely smaller than the distance of alpha and beta. I just don't get what difference does it make if x > y or x < y.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. The reason you would want to consider the cases $x\leq y$ and $x > y$ seperately for this problem is because for $t\in\mathbb{R},$ the definition of $\vert t\vert$ is $
\vert t\vert=
\begin{cases}
 -t&\text{if}\,\ t < 0\\
 t&\text{if}\,\ t\geq 0.\\
\end{cases}
$ 

Now consider replacing $t$ with $x-y.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I've updated my "progress"

Comment: Ok. The line: "We know that $$\left | y-x \right |=\left | x -\alpha \right |-\left | \beta - y \right |$$" I think this is not true. Also, your proof ends up with the statement, $$ \left | y-x \right |=\left | y-x \right |$$

which is a statement that is always true anyway, so you haven't proven anything, even if the previous line were true.

Remember that you need to prove that if  $\alpha < x < \beta $ and $\alpha < y < \beta  $ then $ \left | x-y \right |< \beta -\alpha $.

Comment: This means you have to start with the *assumptions* that $\alpha < x < \beta $ and $\alpha < y < \beta  $ and logically deduce (with implication statements), that $ \left | x-y \right |< \beta -\alpha $. Logically deducing instead that $ \left | y-x \right |=\left | y-x \right |$ or that $1=1$ is a bit silly and doesn't prove what you should be trying to prove.

Comment: I just keep going in circles. I do not know how to logically deduce it with implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\vert x-y\vert:=
\begin{cases}
 -(x-y)&\text{if}\,\ x-y < 0\\
 x-y&\text{if}\,\ x-y\geq 0.\\
\end{cases}
$

i.e.,

$
\vert x-y\vert:=
\begin{cases}
 -x+y&\text{if}\,\ x < y\\
 x-y&\text{if}\,\ x\geq y.\\
\end{cases}
$

We consider the two cases, $x<y,$ and $x\geq y,$ separately.

Suppose that $x<y.$

Adding $-x$ to both sides of the assumption $ y < \beta$ gives: $ y-x < \beta - x.$

Adding $(\beta-x-\alpha)$ to both sides of the assumption $\alpha < x$ gives: $ \beta - x < \beta - \alpha. $

We have $ y-x < \beta - x$ and $ \beta - x < \beta - \alpha. $ It follows that $y-x < \beta - \alpha.$

Since $x<y,\ $ it follows that  $\vert x - y \vert = -x + y = y - x < \beta - \alpha.$

This proves that $ \left | x-y \right |< \beta -\alpha $ for the case $x<y.$

Now try to imitate this proof to prove the original statement for the other case, $x\geq y.$

Comment: thank you. Updated my question with the solution for the other case

Comment: Yeah your proof looks good, although you could improve it by explaining what you're doing at each step.